# Reactjs - translating a class component to a functional one with hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs. I'm following a React online tutorial and decided to translate any class components to functional ones to practise hooks. I've done a few very basic ones and now I'm stuck on that. The class one below works fine. The one below that I transleted to generates an error that monsters.map is not a function. Please advise.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      monsters: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({monsters: users}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          this.state.monsters.map(monster => <h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>)
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Below is my conversion into a functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';


function AppFn() {
  const [monsters, setMonster] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => setMonster({monsters: users}));
  },[]);

  return(
    <div className="App funct">
        {
          monsters.map(monster => <h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>)
        }
      </div>
  )
}

export default AppFn;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#map` works only on *arrays* and what you are actually doing is passing `monsters` array as a field in an object.

```
.then(users => setMonster({monsters: users}));
```

Replace it with:

```
.then(users => setMonster(users));
```